# Django websocket cannot connect through https request blocked in railway app

Tags: javascript, django

My websocket works fine on localhost. But fails to run when I deploy my project on railway app

(which uses https)

It shows this error in the console log:

first error -

```
    (index):382 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://supreme-key-production.up.railway.app/rooms/bangladesh_ott/' was loaded over HTTPS, but attempted to connect to the insecure WebSocket endpoint 'ws://supreme-key-production.up.railway.app/ws/bangladesh_ott/'. This request has been blocked; this endpoint must be available over WSS.
```

second error -

```
    (index):382 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': An insecure WebSocket connection may not be initiated from a page loaded over HTTPS.
        at window.onload (https://supreme-key-production.up.railway.app/rooms/bangladesh_ott/:382:24)
```

This is in my script :

```js
    window.onload = function() {
        const roomName = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('json-roomname').textContent);
        const userName = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('json-username').textContent);
        const chatSocket = new WebSocket(
            'ws://'
            + window.location.host
            + '/ws/'
            + roomName
            + '/'
        );
        chatSocket.onmessage = function(e) {
            console.log('onmessage')
    
            const data = JSON.parse(e.data);
    
            if (data.message) {
                let html = '<div class="message">';
                    html += '<p class="messsage_username">' + data.username + '</p>';
                    html += '<p class="message_message">' + data.message + '</p></div>';
    
                document.querySelector('#chat-messages').innerHTML += html;
            } else {
                alert('The message was empty!');
            }
        }
    
        chatSocket.onclose = function(e) {
            console.log('onclose')
        }
    
        //
    
        document.querySelector('#chat-message-submit').onclick = function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
    
            const messageInputDom = document.querySelector('#chat-message-input');
            const message = messageInputDom.value;
    
            chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify({
                'message': message,
                'username': userName,
                'room': roomName
            }));
    
            messageInputDom.value = '';
    
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Any solution for this?